# Undefined method 'items_loaded'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Missing something fundamental here. Getting `undefined method 'items_loaded'` when trying to check if [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) is done fetching some items from this API.

**Live app which you can run on the fly**: http://runnable.com/VW9rQx-KiIFfmpII/ajax-affiliates

```
Started GET "/check_items_loaded" at 2015-06-04 17:03:44 +0000
Processing by MainController#check_items_loaded as */*
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)    

NoMethodError (undefined method `items_loaded' for #<Class:0x00000004e694a8>):
  app/controllers/main_controller.rb:12:in `check_items_loaded'
```

**main_controller.rb**

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def index
    # Delay fetching
    # @products = Affiliate.fetch
    @products = Affiliate.delay.fetch

    # Let us know when fetching is done
    Affiliate.set_items_loaded
  end

  def check_items_loaded
    @items_status = Affiliate.items_loaded
    respond_to do |wants|
      wants.js
    end
  end
end
```

**affiliate.rb**

```
require "rest_client"

class Affiliate < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.fetch
    response = RestClient::Request.execute(
      :method => :get,
      :url => "http://api.shopstyle.com/api/v2/products?pid=uid7849-6112293-28&fts=women&offset=0&limit=10"
    )

    @products = JSON.parse(response)["products"].map do |product|
      product = OpenStruct.new(product)
      product
    end
  end

  def self.set_items_loaded
    self.update_all(items_loaded: true)
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get '/check_items_loaded', to: 'main#check_items_loaded', as: :check_items_loaded
```

**20150604120114_add_items_loaded_to_affiliates.rb**

```
class AddItemsLoadedToAffiliates < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_table :affiliates do |t|
      t.column :items_loaded, :boolean, default: false
    end
  end

  def self.down
    change_table :affiliates do |t|
      t.remove :items_loaded
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@items_status = Affiliate.items_loaded
```

`items_loaded` is an *instance* method, not a class method.

Comment: Cool, so what should I do then? Got a similar use case (https://gist.github.com/dt1973/a97a167c21d07e3252a9) where I managed to pull off `@photo_status = Photo.find(params[:id]).attachment_processing` just fine.

Comment: @FlyntHamlock Because `find` returns an instance.

Comment: I see. I tried `@items_status = Affiliate.find(:all).items_loaded` earlier to no avail. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: These items aren't in the db so I reckon I can't look for `params[:id]`?

Comment: @FlyntHamlock Because `find(:all)` returns *all* affiliates, not an instance of an affiliate.

Comment: @FlyntHamlock ... If they're not in the DB I don't even know what you're doing. Affiliates are in the DB. They have an `items_loaded` column with a boolean. (At least if you ran your migration.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant the items fetched by REST Client doesn't get stored in the db. That's probably irrelevant though. Anyway here's the full use case: https://gist.github.com/dt1973/b57d84bf39a75ea47e9b

Comment: So yeah, any idea how to structure my find?

Comment: @FlyntHamlock What are you trying to find? The statuses of *all* Affiliates? Also, doesn't `delay` start a background job? It's not synchronous; the call to `set_items_loaded` will occur before the items are actually loaded. Probably even before the job starts.

Comment: Damn, I was under the impression it was synchronous. Basically I just need to know (via that route) if _all_ the items are done loading so I can load them via Ajax. Previously when I didn't send this to the background, the query to this API would slow down my site by 2-3 seconds which was really bad.

Comment: @FlyntHamlock You still want to do it via `delay`, but the `items_loaded` flag should be set at the end of the job, not in the mainline code. Not sure why you thought it'd be synchronous, delayed_job is explicitly not that, that's its purpose in life. Also if this is a *global* flag do you really need to keep it in each individual affiliate? (You might.) If the item loading is happening in a job then as each affiliate's items are loaded you'd set that affiliate's `items_loaded` flag. You'd have to query the back end from JS, say, and do something exciting when it's finished processing.

Comment: You're right, I was tripping. Not entirely sure what you mean by the rest - I only have one affiliate whose items I'm trying to fetch. Would probably make more sense if you checked out my Gist (https://gist.github.com/dt1973/b57d84bf39a75ea47e9b). There I'm querying the back end from JS via a route. No idea what to do now. Any chance you're available for hire?

Comment: @FlyntHamlock Oh, a single affiliate? Your class method updates *all* affiliates--is that on purpose?

Comment: Not on purpose. Was given to me by this other guy here on SO. So how much you want to help me fix that gist? :)

Comment: @FlyntHamlock Please use the contact info from profile.